# iOS bundle size increases by twice of added launch image size

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added a launch image for retina iPad in PNG format which was ~4.5 MB. After that, the archive size of the bundle increased by 9 MB (based on "Estimated App Store Size" in Organizer). It looks like the image was somehow duplicated in the bundle but I'm sure that the image was added just once. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? I am using Xcode 4.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the default Xcode build setting "Yes" for "Compress PNG Files" under "Packaging" group bloated the original PNG file size of my launch image. Details can be found here:

http://imageoptim.com/xcode.html

When I changed the setting to "No", the archive size was back to normal reflecting the original PNG file size.